# Configuring WebPack with Moment TimeZone CDN

Tags: webpack, momentjs, webpack-4, moment-timezone

I am using *WebPack 4* to build my *TypeScript* applications.

One of my modules uses the `moment-timezone` library, for example...

```
import * as moment from 'moment-timezone';
$('#label-locale').text(moment.locale());
```

and this works as expected.

To make better use of caching, I would like to reference `moment` and `moment-timezone` from a *Content Delivery Network (CDN)* and have added the following to my `HTML` page:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

I also modified the `webpack.config.js` as follows:

```
module.exports = {
    externals: {
        'jquery': 'jQuery',
        'moment': 'moment-timezone'
    }
};
```

Now, when I run my code, I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: timezone is not defined
```

I am new to *WebPack* and have tried things like adding `'timezone': 'moment-timezone'` to the `externals` without success.

Any help/direction would be very much appreciated.

Comment: `'moment-timezone': 'moment-timezone'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was over-thinking this.  `moment-timezone` actually 'just' extends the `moment` object to include `moment.tz`, so all I had to do was modify the `webpack.config.js` as follows:

```
module.exports = {
    externals: {
        'jquery': 'jQuery',
        'moment-timezone': 'moment'
    }
};
```

So instead of `WebPack` effectively *building* the whole definition tree from the `node_modules/moment-timezone` the `moment` object had already been updated by the CDN reference.  At least, I think that is what is happening.